# Using wirebox in coldbox how do I create a bean from a model

Tags: coldfusion, coldbox

I am not good with the terminology yet, so please forgive/correct me.  Also I have no idea hw to use Coldspring, etc, so I am trying to just use wirebox.

I want to not use the beanFactory plugin and just call wirebox methods straight from my model.

Currently I can use this

```
<cfproperty name="bf" inject="coldbox:plugin:BeanFactory" scope="variables" />
```

How do I do it so that I can call wirebox's getInstance method instead of beanFactory's getModel?

Answer (score 1):

Within the handler, you can have Wirebox inject beans using property injection (much like what you posted).

**Tag Based**

```
<cfproperty name='myModel' inject='id:MyModel' />
```

**Script Based**

```
property name='myModel' inject='id:MyModel';
```

You can then use the model anywhere in the handler by simply calling `myModel.someMethod()`.

It's also worth noting that if you are injecting using the model's ID, then the value of `inject` isn't required. Wirebox will attempt to look up the model using the name you gave it. You could simplify it.

**Tag Based**

```
<cfproperty name='myModel' inject />
```

**Script Based**

```
property name='myModel' inject;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the answer you are looking for but...

In the handler you can do this.

```
var oMyModel = populateModel("myModel");
```

In a model  you can do this.

```
var oMyModel = createobject("component", "myModel");
```

Does this answer what you need?

Comment: Not really, the problem is that my model objects need to be autowired when instantiated.